# Community Cloud security Model for chatter

Tags: community-cloud

We are trying to setup a community cloud, currently we have a service cloud app with users assigned to it and used primarily around case management.

Now when we setup community cloud, we would like to understand the security behind the chatter posts that is done on the cases by the Service cloud console user vs Community user who has access to same set of cases.

1. If I am a Community cloud user, can I @ mention to an Service cloud user (I believe not)
2. If I am a Community cloud user, if i post a comment on a Case, can the Service cloud user who has access to the case can see it
3. If I am a Service cloud user, can I @mention to an Community cloud user
4. If I am a Service cloud user, if i post a comment on a Case, can the Community cloud user who has access to the case can see it

We are trying to understand the security model of chatter between Service cloud user and Community cloud user.

Can you anyone please share any good documentation/links to understand the security model for Community cloud. We want the chatter communications done on the case by Service cloud user not to be accessible for Community cloud user.

Also phase 2 of the project would be have one more community setup; also nice to understand the security model if we have 2 communities.

Comment: Would you clarify your question by telling us the type of community cloud license you're using? Is this customer, partner customer plus, or something else? Answer to that makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: We are planning to implement both communities: Employee and Customer community.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two very different types of communities, the answers to your questions are not straightforward nor are they simple to answer. Much will depend on how you set up your communities, whether you decide to "join" the two, operate them separately and how you configure OWD for each license and permission sets for your users. In other words, you're in control of what you want your users to see. Here's a link to a page with a chart of the permissions & objects that are available for each of the two licenses: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US.

I recommend that in addition to the Salesforce Help for Communities that begins at [Salesforce Communities Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_overview.htm&language=en_US), you'll want to refer to [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/) and the [Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/?filter_text=&service=All%20Services&select_type=Security&version=37.0&lang=en-us&sort=title) after which you'll then need to dig deeper into configuring Chatter or Chatter Answers along with Cases or the Service Cloud Console depending on your implementation. You'll find links to all the docs you might want at [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/).